# Excel search and replace with search result

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Hi there I have an Excel file with 2 Worksheets, one is a table with some names and values. And the Other one is a list of the names, but with more information to it (CSV format).

Worksheet 1 (Genus):

```
g__Mannheimia 
g__Peptococcus
g__unspecific_Proteobacteria
g__Acinetobacter
```

Worksheet 2 (Tree):

```
d__Bacteria;p__Proteobacteria;c__Gammaproteobacteria;o__Enterobacterales;f__Enterobacteriaceae;g__Salmonella
d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli;o__Lactobacillales;f__Streptococcaceae;g__Streptococcus
d__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteriota;c__Actinobacteria;o__Mycobacteriales;f__Mycobacteriaceae;g__Mycobacterium
d__Bacteria;p__Proteobacteria;c__Gammaproteobacteria;o__Enterobacterales;f__Enterobacteriaceae;g__Klebsiella
d__Bacteria;p__Proteobacteria;c__Gammaproteobacteria;o__Pseudomonadales;f__Moraxellaceae;g__Acinetobacter
```

What I'm trying to do is, search for the names in worksheet 1 in worksheet 2, and replace the name of worksheet 1 with the text from worksheet 2. This can be done by hand with the search and replace function, but because it's a huge amount of data I'm trying to find another way to do it.

I wrote this macro to try to iterate on both worksheets and match the names, but it didn't work.

```
Sub Macro1()
Set myrange = Genus.Range("A4:A174")
For Each cell In myrange

Dim find1
Dim replace1

find1 = cell.Value
replace1 = Tree.Range("A1:A7372").Value

    Genus.Cells.Replace What:=find1, Replacement:=replace1, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Next cell
End Sub
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim myrange As Range
    Set myrange = Genus.Range("A4:A174")
    Dim replace1 As Range
    Set replace1 = Tree.Range("A1:A7372")

    For Each cell In myrange
        Dim find1 As Range
        Set find1 = replace1.Find(What:=cell.Text, LookAt:=xlPart,   LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
        If Not find1 Is Nothing Then
            cell.Value = find1.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did the trick, I also had to add Sheets("Genus") and Sheets("Tree")

Comment: I would suggest using the CodeName of the sheets rather than the Tab name. That way if for some reason you want to change the tab from "Genus" to say "TheGenus" your code will still work. I had assumed that the sheet names in your original code *were* the sheet CodeNames... <G>